# Stream-uploading large files via Spring WebClient

Tags: spring, file-upload, inputstream, flux, spring-webclient

I am having the same problem as referred to here.

[Stream upload 'POST' in Spring WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61506325/stream-upload-post-in-spring-webclient)

I need to upload large files via Spring WebClient and I don't want to read the files in memory to do that.

I have the files stored in Minio S3 bucket and the interface allows me to receive the file as java.io.InputStream.

Then I would like to stream that as an upload body to another service endpoint.

The solution, which gives an error of `Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported for bodyType=org.springframework.web.reactive.function.BodyInserters` is produced the following way:

```
public String uploadFile(String fileId, String fileName) {
        InputStream fileInputStream = minioClient.getObject(bucketName, fileId);

        return webClient.post()
                .uri(properties.getUrl())
                .contentType(APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.set(FILE_NAME, fileName);
                })
                .bodyValue(BodyInserters.fromResource(fileInputStream)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(String.class)
                .blockFirst();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using `DataBufferUtils.readInputStream(..)` ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/buffer/DataBufferUtils.html#readInputStream-java.util.concurrent.Callable-org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferFactory-int-)) to create a `Flux<DataBuffer>`. And then use the appropriate `BodyInserters.fromDataBuffers(..)` ([javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/BodyInserters.html#fromDataBuffers-T-)) to pass to `.bodyValue()`.  This should correctly not load the entire file into memory, but rather buffer and send it chunk by chunk.

I'm not sure if this will work with `application/octet-stream` as the content type as I haven't been able to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.bodyValue()` with `.body()` and it will work.

```java
     public String uploadFile(String fileId, String fileName) {
        InputStream fileInputStream = minioClient.getObject(bucketName, fileId);

        return webClient.post()
                .uri(properties.getUrl())
                .contentType(APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.set(FILE_NAME, fileName);
                })
                .body(BodyInserters.fromResource(fileInputStream)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(String.class)
                .blockFirst();
    }
```